# How do you dynamically add a button/plugin to TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor in my page. I would like to add/remove buttons/plugins from the toolbar based on things happening else where in the page. I am looking for a solution that avoids destroying and recreating the editor. Is there a tinyMCE command to do this? Something like

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceInsertPlugin", pluginName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load plugins without reinitializing the editor.
But with buttons it is possible:

Create button on the fly:

```
  ed.addButton('example', {
     title : 'example.desc',
     image : '../jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/example/img/example.gif',
     onclick : function() {
        ed.windowManager.alert('Hello world!! Selection: ' + ed.selection.getContent({format : 'text'}));
     }
  });
```

Removal: 
`$('.mce_example').parent('td').remove();`